# Calling out a form within a form (PHP)

Tags: php, sqlite

I'm trying to call out a form within a form where the second form action does not work. It didn't parse. My sample program have one main form which is attached to my submit button and inner form would be a download button.

Updated code:

```
<?php
$fullPath = "staff.doc";
<form id="Staff" name="Staff" method="post" action="download_preview.php">
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"fullPath\" value=\"$fullPath\"/>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Download\"/>";
echo "<input type=\"submit\" id=\"Submit\" name=\"Submit\" value\="Submit\"/>";
echo "</form>";

<?php
switch($_POST['submit']) 
{
case "Submit":

break;
case "Download":
$fullPath = $_POST['fullPath'];
// download file

     opendir("$fullPath");

break;
default:
}
?>
```

I have updated with the multiple handler approach. But i'm still not able to call out the download path. The code for the download was working previously with a single form.

Comment: Perhaps it's a bit ambiguous when you say "call out". Can you be more specific? Is it functionally separate from the outer form (can it be a sibling?)? Also, are you aware that a form can include multiple submit controls, and that the *value* of the one the user clicks will be sent with the request?

Comment: Any examples to go along ? The issue is there is two buttons inside the form. When the download button is clicked, it will call out download.php. If submit button is clicked, it will go to next page.

Comment: And that's the desired behavior? You mean you want that, and it's not working presently?

Comment: ya, as you can see from my form now. It's a form within a form. That's why it's only able to call out the outer form which is the submit button and not the download button.

Comment: I modified my answer to include two possible approaches. But seriously; "call out" is a confusing term in this context... :-/

Comment: Are you getting into that case of the switch? Do you have any errors in your logs? What have you tried to debug this? I can lead you to the water; but learning to drink is on you. If you know that download code works, then try to debug and find out why it's not executing or why it's not working any more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in [the XHTML spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#prohibitions),

> ***form***: must not contain other form elements.

And if it's in the spec, you should not rely on how any given user-agent vendor handles it. And just in case you aren't familiar with how the folks over there use phrases like "must not", there's this:

> ***Must***:
> In this specification, the word "must" is to be interpreted as a mandatory requirement on the implementation or on Strictly Conforming XHTML Documents, depending upon the context. The term "shall" has the same definition as "must".

EDIT: I was curious, and found that [the HTML5 spec](http://developers.whatwg.org/forms.html#the-form-element) also includes language forbidding nested forms.

EDIT (code suggestions):

## method one: the sibling-forms approach

```
<?php $fullPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/doc/store"."$T"; ?>
<form id="Staff" name="Staff" method="post" action="gotonextpage.php">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value='Submit'>
</form>
<form name="download" action="download.php" method="post">";
  <input type="hidden" name="fullPath" value="<?php echo $fullPath ?>"/>";
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download"/>";
</form>
```

## method two: the multi-purpose handler approach

```
<?php $fullPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/doc/store"."$T"; ?>
<form id="Staff" name="Staff" method="post" action="downlod_or_gotonextpage.php">
  <input type="submit" name="Submit" value='Submit'>
  <input type="hidden" name="fullPath" value="<?php echo $fullPath ?>"/>";
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Download"/>";
</form>
```

And then make downlod_or_gotonextpage.php

```
switch($_POST['submit']) {
  case "Submit":
    // go to next page, either with 302, include, or whatever is appropriate
    break;
  case "Download":
    // do downloading, perhaps also with a 302 first...
    break;
  default:
    // 404, or 302 to the original form page
}
```

Comment: Ok, understood now. But is there anyway that i can call out the action of download.php for the download button ?

Comment: If I understand what you want correctly, you should either place your "download" form *outside* the other, or else have your other page recognize the value sent with the submit parameter of the request and redirect to the download.

Comment: Hi, I have updated my code with your useful switch case. However, i'm not able to download the file yet. Did I call out wrongly ?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't put a form within a form according to HTML. I'm not quite sure why, in this example, you'd need that anyway. Get rid of the outer form.

Comment: Is there anyway to call out the inner button in order to post the action of download.php ?

Comment: You can dynamically call that button's click action with JS, if that's what you mean...?

Comment: As you see, now i have two buttons known as submit and download. I would like to call out the download button without the form. Since it is not possible to call out a form within a form. Is it possible? I would like to call out the button to call the download.php